# com.espertech.esper.schedule.ScheduleSlot in 5.5.0 version

Tags: esper

I have moved from **esper-4-9-0** to **esper-5-5-0** ( the last version supported in **JDK 1.7**)

Many of the classes have been moved to different folders.

[image]

But with the poor documentation, I am unable to find *com.espertech.esper.schedule.ScheduleSlot* in new version.

Assist me if you know the replacement

Answer (score 0):

Schedule slot is an internal API that one would only use for programming extensions. I looked it up and it has been replaced by a long. You can find it among the JavaDoc index. The documentation is online at [Javadoc](http://esper.espertech.com/release-5.5.0/esper-javadoc/index.html). I would look at the extension code examples for the replacement and if you can't find it look at the time window code for example.

Comment: Gone through it but did not find